# Why can I not create a directory on my external hard-drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, command-line, permission, filesystem

When I try to make a new directory on my external hard-drive I get a message saying that it is a "Read-only file system"

```
LU06296APPLE:~ fortinok$ mkdir /Volumes/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/working_files
mkdir: /Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/working_files: Read-only file system
```

However, it looks like from the permissions, that the owner of the drive should be able to "write"

```
drwxrwxrwt@  5 root      admin                    170 Feb 16 09:02 .
drwxr-xr-x  34 root      wheel                   1224 Feb 13 16:00 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin                      1 Feb  2 08:28 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxr-xr-x   1 fortinok  LONGWOOD\Domain Users   4096 Feb 15 22:34 Seagate Backup Plus Drive
```

Since I am the logged in user:

```
LU06296APPLE:~ fortinok$ who
fortinok console  Feb  2 08:58 
fortinok ttys000  Feb 13 07:55
```

and I "own" the drive, why can I not make a new directory?

(Note: I am also unable to make a new directory using Finder.)

Comment: What format? NTFS?

Comment: Is that disk formated in NTFS ?

Comment: The whole drive is mounted read-only, so the individual permissions are not important. Can you eject the drive (in Finder) and then turn it off/on again so it gets mounted again?

Comment: @Tetsujin how can I determine if it is NTSF?

Comment: Get Info on the drive itself. Near the top, General > created:x Modified:x Format:...

Comment: Then you either need to fiddle in Terminal [I'll let someone else do that bit, not my strong point] or use something like Paragon NTFS or Tuxera

Comment: @KennyPeanuts If it is your drive, empty (besides some useless Seagate Win/Mac backup apps) and no need to attach it to Windows systems just reformat it to "1 Partition Mac OS X Extended (Journaled)"

Comment: Thanks for the info on NTFS.  Seagate, the maker of the drive has a driver that you can instal to allow writing to NTSF for this drive.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: ah, yes, there's a version of Paragon specifically for Seagate. Glad you found it.